# Rails Active Record Not Allowing Saves

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console, exists

I have renamed the model to test model for this. I have a empty table and no matter what I enter for the email it always says there is already a row with that email. I've completely reset my db. Email is a non unique index for testmodel whose primary key is id. This model has_many of a few other models and belongs to nothing.

```
irb(main):001:0> @app = testmodel.new
#excluded column data
irb(main):002:0> @app.email= 'test'
=> "test"
irb(main):003:0> @app.save
←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
←[1m←[35mtestmodel Exists (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `test_models`  WHERE `test_models`.`email` = 'test' LIMIT 1
←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mROLLBACK←[0m
=> false
```

Comment: What does @app.errors show? (after unsuccessfully trying to save)

Comment: Ah that helped me fix it. Apparently when we did a conversion to devise there were some new requirements that weren't passing but it wasn't telling us  the right reason for.  Any idea why it says the email already exists though?

Comment: @app.errors says that the email is already taken? if your DB table is empty this is weird, should be a devise config issue, but I'll need more info to know

Comment: I fixed it.  In the end there was no reason for that error message though. Thanks for the help. I wish I could rep you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when we did a conversion to devise there were problems with how the password was handled.
In the end I had to use @app.errors to realize that but its still very strange that rails was saying the email was already taken.